# Average over a column if text in another column maches

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I want to compute the average over one column if the text in another column matches a certain text.

eg:

```
A      B      C
aa     6      =AVERAGEIF(B1:B6;EXACT(A1:A6;"aa"))
bb     15  
aa     8  
bb     17  
cc     1  
aa     5
```

But the value in C gets 1. Why? How can I do what I want?

Comment: Try this =AVERAGEIF(A:A,"aa",B:B)

Comment: I am getting `Err:501` (Invalid character)

Comment: In fact is LibreOffice Calc the reason why it dose so?

Comment: I do not know, how can I verify that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the AVERAGEIFS() function instead of AVERAGEIF().  See below:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B6,A1:A6,"aa")
```

This will yield as result of 6.3333.

Cheers.

Comment: I am still getting that error in both excel (Windows) and calc (Ubuntu)